# Is there an alternative to strsplit?

Tags: matlab

I have an old version of MATLAB which lacks the very useful `strsplit` function documented [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html). Is there a way to replicate this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! Use `regexp` with the `'split'` option as follows. Note that it is necessary to escape characters which have special meaning when calling `regexp`. <del>regexescape = @(delim) regexprep(delim,'[\^\$()\<[{\\|>.*+\?]','\$0')</del>

One line replacement function for `strsplit` (courtesy of @AndrasDeak):

```
mystrsplit = @(str,delim) regexp(str,regexptranslate('escape',delim),'split')
```

Test cases:

```
>> strsplit('hi.mom','.')

ans = 

    'hi'    'mom'

>> mystrsplit('hi.mom','.')

ans = 

    'hi'    'mom'
```